# C : function that calculates the sum of an array using pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

the purpose is to return the sum of *a into *sum 
but I am not very good with pointers, I believe there should be a & somewhere

```
int sumArray (int * a, int len , int * sum ){
    if (a==NULL || sum==NULL ) return -1;
      int i;
      for (i=0;i<len;i++){
          sum[i]+=a[i];
      }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: please post also an execution of your code

Comment: i dont have yet i just created this function but the question in the book is /* Sums the elements of a, an array of length len , and
2 * writes the sum to where sum references. Returns 0,
3 * unless a or sum is NULL , in which case returns -1.
4 */
5 int sumArray (int * a, int len , int * sum);

Comment: Try to follow these guidelines: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: In this case, you have an array that has ‘len’ elements, and you want to calculate the sum of all elements, right ?

Comment: yes right @Hitokiri

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand from your comment, the parameter sum is not an array, but rather the variable where the sum will be stored. And since sum is a pointer, to store values into it, you must access its value this way : (*sum)

```
int sumArray (int * a, int len , int * sum ){
    if (a==NULL || sum==NULL ) return -1;
      int i;
      (*sum) = 0 ;
      for (i=0;i<len;i++){
         (*sum) += a[i];
      }
      return 0;
}
```